# App script - Add new file to spreadsheet with folder and url no generate new spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a parent folder called movies and child folders with movies inside
movies / luca (2020) /luca-1080.mkv

The script thanks to [idfurw] (https://stackoverflow.com/users/16125139/idfurw) does the following:

- Generate the name of the child folder (luca (2020))
- generates the link of the corresponding movie (link gdrive of the movie)

This is the script:

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
  
  var folders = foldersID.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var name = folder.getName();

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var link = file.getUrl();
      sheet.appendRow([name, link]);
    }
  }
}
```

but:

- Creates a spreadsheet every time it is launched (which I don't want that) ❌

What i want to achieve

- Take a spreadsheet from the id or name ✅
- If I add new folders with movies to the parent folder and when running the script again it only adds the missing ones to the spreadsheet✅

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Insert your Google Sheet's ID here");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Get existing names in column A
  var existingNames = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);

  var newData = [];

  if(lastRow == 0){
    //Append header row
    sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
    lastRow++;
  }
  
  var folders = foldersID.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var name = folder.getName();

    if(existingNames.includes(name)){
      //name already exist in the sheets, Skip
      continue;
    }

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var link = file.getUrl();

      //add new data
      newData.push([name, link]);
    }
  }

  //Write new data to sheets
  if(newData.length>0){
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
}
```

### Modifications done:

- Instead of creating a new spreadsheet. Open a spreadsheet using its file id.
- Get all existing movie names in column A
- Add header row if the sheet is empty
- Append new data in the active sheet. Skip movie names in the drive that is already existing in the sheet's column A

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update the answer accordingly

Comment: Thats work very good.. thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

This code worked well for me

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldersID = DriveApp.getFolderById("10Zw76wu2UNz3jufimUFGd8OJErPGnsih");
  var foldername = foldersID.getName();
  var folderlisting = 'listado de ' + foldername;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Insert your Google Sheet's ID here");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Get existing names in column A
  var existingNames = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);

  var newData = [];

  if(lastRow == 0){
    //Append header row
    sheet.appendRow( ['name','link'] );
    lastRow++;
  }
  
  var folders = foldersID.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var name = folder.getName();

    if(existingNames.includes(name)){
      //name already exist in the sheets, Skip
      continue;
    }

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var link = file.getUrl();

      //add new data
      newData.push([name, link]);
    }
  }

  //Write new data to sheets
  if(newData.length>0){
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
}
```